# ast.literal_eval power support

Tags: python, eval

How to evaluate user input mathematical expressions such as power safely?
Tried using `ast.literal_eval` but it raises an exception.

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval('2**2')
ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.BinOp object at ...>
```

Comment: Hint: `2**2` is not a literal.

Comment: `2+3` is not a literal as well, and yet it works.

Comment: According to the documentation, it shouldn't work, so I would consider that leaking a private internal implementation detail, and would not rely on it. I wouldn't bet, for example, that it works the same way in IronPython, Jython, PyPy, Typhon, Pynie, PythonOMR, TrufflePython, etc.

Comment: See my answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197673/using-pythons-eval-vs-ast-literal-eval/68732605#68732605

Comment: @Sawel `2+3` works? I can't get it to work in Python 3.8.10 (same error as OP) or 2.7.18 (`ValueError: malformed string`), but maybe it was patched after you wrote that comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `seval` package for arithmetic operations and literals safe evaluation.

```
>>> import seval
>>> seval.safe_eval('2 ** 2')
4
```

Answer (score 2):

`ast.literal_eval` (although it actually supports addition and substraction) is intended for evaluating literals only. To safely evaluate mathematical expressions, you should construct the AST yourself using `ast.parse(some_expression, mode="eval")` and check if it only contains literals and mathematical operations using `ast.walk()`. To evaluate an AST use something like `eval(compile(the_ast, "<string>", "eval"))`.

See this website for more information about ASTs: https://greentreesnakes.readthedocs.io/